# weak convergence in strongly continuous semi-group of operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $\{T(t)\}$ is a strongly continuous semi-group of operators. If $w-\lim_{t\to0^+} t^{-1} [T(t)x-x] = y$, prove that $$\lim_{t\to0^+} t^{-1} [T(t)x-x] = y.$$

Comment: Welcome to math.se! People will be more likely to answer your question if you tell us what you are stuck on and why. Please don't post problems like this without context.

Comment: I am going to prove that for every $f\in X^*$, $\frac{d}{dt}f(T(t)x)$ exists, then I can use integral to solve this, but I simple proved that it has a right derivative, and don't know how to prove the left derivative exists

Comment: See my answer at this question. [$\{T(t):t\geq 0\}$ is a strongly continuous semi-group, suppose $x\in \mathbb{X}$, $w-\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{t}(T(t)-I)x=y$, show that $y=Ax$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778207/ttt-geq-0-is-a-strongly-continuous-semi-group-suppose-x-in-mathbbx)